# Match everythin between tag as comment

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3

I would like to highlight every thing between

```
!&
    some explanation
&!
```

As a comment.

I know comment are match with

```
- name: comment.line.exclamation-mark.fortran
  match: (?i)\!.*$
```

in my `fortran.YAML-tmLanguage`.
But I don't see how to extend this to the case above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the comments are multiline, you need to split the regex into two expressions, one called begin and one called end.
This allows you to parse multiple lines.

I dont really use YAML, but this code from the C tmLanguage should get you started (Comment style is `/* COMMENT */`):

```
<dict>
    <key>begin</key> <string>\s*/\*</string>
    <key>captures</key>
    <dict>
        <key>0</key> <dict> <key>name</key> 
        <string>punctuation.definition.comment.c</string> </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>end</key> <string>\*/</string>
    <key>name</key> <string>comment.block.c</string>
</dict>
```

So you could use `\s\!\&` for the begin-tag and `\&\!` for the end-tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found the below work. Thanks @LinuCC.

```
# order matter: this block comment syntax should be before the line comment syntax
- name: comment.block.fortran
  begin: (?i)\!&
  end: (?i)&\!
  captures:
    '0': {name: comment.line.exclamation-mark.fortran}

- name: comment.line.exclamation-mark.fortran
  match: (?i)\!.*$
```

To make comment toggling work you also need, in another file,

```
# [PackageDev] target_format: plist, ext: tmPreferences
---
name: Comments
uuid: 40e092f2-ee49-4cbd-8afb-4a5c4f581463
scope: source.fortran

settings:

  shellVariables:
  - name: TM_COMMENT_START
    value: '! '
  - name: TM_COMMENT_START_2
    value: '!&'
  - name: TM_COMMENT_END_2
    value: '&!'
```